# Append an item to html document

Tags: jquery, html

I have been making a small project where you can add an movie to a list with Jquery, its working fine, however every time i add an element it prints out on the page like

```
SevenLord Of the RingsUp
```

I would prefer

```
Seven
Lord of the rings
Up
```

Im new to jquery and cant find out my problem.
This is my code

Jquery

```
$("#sparafilm").click(function(){
    var thevalue = $("#titel").val();
    $("ol").append(thevalue);
});
```

HTML where it should be printed out

```
    Titel:
    <input type="text" name="Titel" id="titel">
    <br>
    Betyg:
    <input type="text" name="Betyg">
    <br>
    <button id="sparafilm" value="Spara film"> Spara film</button>

    <ol>



    </ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

append is used to insert new element

try this

```
$("ol").append('<li>'+thevalue+'</li>');
```

Comment: Ahh that did the trick:
I tried with ('<li>'thevalue'</li>'); Before but that did not seem to work, so i missed out on the plus.
Thanks :)

Comment: @tryingsohard glad to hear that. welcome to stackoverflow. dont forget to check as answer then